# how to stop beautiful soup from including span tags but still display content?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseUrl = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/'

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 '
}
productLinks = []
productNameArray = []
productPriceArray = []
for x in range(1, 6):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/639/bourbon-whiskey?pg=. 
    {x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    productList = soup.find_all('li', class_='product-grid__item')
    productName = soup.find_all('p', class_='product-card__name')
    productPrice = soup.find_all('p', class_='product-card__price')

    for item in productList:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productLinks.append(baseUrl + link['href'])
        for name in item.find('p', class_='product-card__name'):
            productNameArray.append(name)
        for price in item.find('p', class_='product-card__price'):
            productPriceArray.append(price)



for x in range(len(productLinks)):
    print('name = ', productNameArray[x], 'price = ', productPriceArray[x], 'link = 
    ', productLinks[x])

print('number of products', len(productLinks))
```

Here is a sample of the output (not all 97 items)

```
name =   Ezra Brooks 7 Year Old Bourbon  price =   £54.95  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/35027/ezra-brooks-7-year-old-bourbon

name =   Eagle Rare 10 Year Old  price =   £40.45  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/19992/eagle-rare-10-year-old

name =   Woodford Reserve Distiller's Select  price =   £35.95  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/1251/woodford-reserve-distillers-select

name =   Wild Turkey Longbranch  price =   £38.45  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/50118/wild-turkey-longbranch

name =   Four Roses Single Barrel Bourbon  price =   £44.95  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/10251/four-roses-single-barrel-bourbon

name =   Buffalo Trace Bourbon  price =   £26.95  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/15620/buffalo-trace-bourbon

name =   Woodford Reserve Masters price =   £84.45  link =  
https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/47648/woodford-reserve-masters-brandy-cask- 
finish

name =  <span class="product-card__name-secondary">Brandy Cask Finish</span> price =   
£29.95  link =  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/22222/bulleit-bourbon-whiskey

name =  <span class="product-card__name-secondary">Port Finish</span> price =   
£32.95  link =  https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com//p/1237/wild-turkey-101
```

How exactly can i remove the spans tag but not what is within them?

I wrote this with the help of [how to scrape the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCuPv3tf2Hg&ab_channel=JohnWatsonRooney) but I don't have a need to go to the product page and grab reviews as well so I had to change some of it.

Answer (score 1):

Im stupid just use the .getText() function and all is good!!

example:

```
        for name in item.find('p', class_='product-card__name'):
        productNameArray.append(name.**getText()**)
```

and boom all tags are removed.

Comment: While it is great to find answers yourself, double check that it is a good answer in terms of formatting and functionality - This one needs some improvment.